# "Unknown escape sequence" error in Go

Tags: regex, syntax, go

I have the following function written in Go.  The idea is the function has a string passed to it and returns the first IPv4 IP address found.  If no IP address is found, an empty string is returned.

```
func parseIp(checkIpBody string) string {
    reg, err := regexp.Compile("[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+")
    if err == nil {
        return ""
    }   
    return reg.FindString(checkIpBody)
}
```

The compile-time error I'm getting is

> unknown escape sequence: .

How can I tell Go that the `'.'` is the actual character I'm looking for?  I thought escaping it would do the trick, but apparently I'm wrong.

Comment: It's an old question but every day people have problems with regexes. One very very useful thing to do when working with regexes (regardless of language used) is to print regex pattern to verify if it is really what you think it is.

Comment: this question is also relevant for prometheus (promql regex)

Answer (score 188, accepted):

The `\` backslash  isn't being interpreted by the regex parser, it's being interpreted in the string literal. You should escape the backslash again:

```golang
regexp.Compile("[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+")
```

A string quoted with `"` double-quote characters is known as an "**interpreted** string literal" in Go. Interpreted string literals are like string literals in most languages: `\` backslash  characters aren't included literally, they're used to give special meaning to the next character. The source must include `\\` two backslashes in a row to obtain an a single backslash character in the parsed value.

Go has another alternative which can be useful when writing string literals for regular expressions: a "**raw** string literal" is quoted by `` ` `` backtick characters. There are no special characters in a raw string literal, so as long as your pattern doesn't include a backtick you can use this syntax without escaping anything:

```golang
regexp.Compile(`[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+`)
```

These are described in [the "String literals" section of the Go spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals).

Comment: This does not really work for the desired purpose - validating IP. For example: `"1a2.3.4.5"` is accepted by this regexp as a valid input.

Comment: Not so - there's no way "1a2." matches "[0-9]+\."

Answer (score 1):

IPv4 address (accurate capture)

Matches 0.0.0.0 through 255.255.255.255

Use this regex to match IP numbers with accurracy.

Each of the 4 numbers is stored into a capturing group, so you can access them for further processing.

```
"(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])"
```

Comment: Nice thorough regex.  Thanks.

Comment: Considering the complexity of the regex I would probably choose to convert the string to integers and check that way instead.  A year from now I doubt I'd remember the details of that expression very well.  That kind of code has bitten me before.  Go libraries might even have support for that kind of check...  For now I'm just using relying on the string sent from the server being correct as long as it is 4 bytes separated by dots (".").

Comment: To make that easier to read, I usually do:

`numBlock="(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])"
regexPattern=numBlock + "\\." + numBlock + "\\." + numBlock + "\\." + numBlock
`