# Golang regex not parsing correctly

Tags: regex

I'm using this functional regex `\/.*?([^:\/\s]+)` that seems to work fine in other languages, but Go doesn't seem to like it.

What this does is extracts the second part of a URL string between the `/`.
So for example `path/deeper/very/deep/file.html`, I just want to replace `/deeper` with something else.

Here is my code

```
finalPath := "path/deeper/very/deep/file.html"
reg, _ := regexp.Compile("\\/.*?([^:\\/\\s]+)")
fmt.Println(reg.ReplaceAllString(finalPath, "<fruit>"))
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

=== EDIT ===
In case someone is interested, the good answer for me was `(^[^\\W\/]*)\/([^\\W\/]*)` then I just put the first part back.

Comment: What error message are you getting? (I ran it myself and saw the error message: "Unknown escape sequence"). Have you tried googling the error message? (First result is another SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6770913/1061413).

Comment: The downvotes are because you did not post the error, nor show any effort of trying to understand it.

Comment: @OneOfOne Why do you say that? I've spend a long time writing that regex, it worked well on other platforms, and when I try the exact same on Go it doesn't work. There was no error message, it was just not selecting the correct thing I needed it to select, what else should I write? Maybe I should remove Go tag as people will continue downvoting.

Comment: It's a pretty typical issue in languages that use back-slashes to encode escapes and use strings as regexes. That the answer is pretty easy to search probably had a lot more to do with the downvoting than anything related to the Go community.

Comment: @DaveNewton it wasn't that the issue, I've accepted the answer only because it was the only answer, not because of it solving anything. It was just a mistype that I forgot the backslash in the question, that I've quickly updated.

Comment: Don't accept an answer if it isn't the right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `\\s` instead of `\s` (or put the whole thing in backquotes so you don't have to double the backslashes).

Comment: It's OK I've found the solution.