# Regex string in Go

Tags: regex, go, mux

I try to use string

```
"/{foo}/{bar:[a-zA-Z0-9=\-\/]+}.{vzz}"
```

in Go.

When I use `"`, I see error:

```
unknown escape sequence
```

When I use `'`, I get:

```
cannot use '\u0000' (type rune) as type string in array or slice literal
unknown escape sequence
```

How I can use this regular expression for MUX in my Go application?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/6770898/13860

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you mean `\` character literally in string literals - it must be escaped additionally

```
"/{foo}/{bar:[a-zA-Z0-9=\\-\\/]+}.{vzz}"
```

otherwise you could use backticks instead of double quotes

```
`/{foo}/{bar:[a-zA-Z0-9=\-\/]+}.{vzz}`
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I confused ' and `

Answer (score 0):

According to Golang Language Specification.

```
string_lit             = raw_string_lit | interpreted_string_lit .
raw_string_lit         = "`" { unicode_char | newline } "`" .
interpreted_string_lit = `"` { unicode_value | byte_value } `"` .
```

So if you do not want to escape anything in your string literal, you need a raw one. and

> The value of a raw string literal is the string composed of the uninterpreted (implicitly UTF-8-encoded) characters between the quotes

Golang does not use single quote `'` as a string literal indicator. And your error with the double quote `"` is due to the compiler trying to escape `\-` and `\/` as a part of the string before the regex interpreter.