# How to check if a string contains dot (period)?

Tags: regex, go

I'd like to find whether a string contains one or more dots. Here is my code:

```
package main 
  
import ( 
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
) 
    
func main() { 
    s1 := "Welcome to dotless string"
    p1 := "."
  
    res1, e := regexp.MatchString(p1, s1) 
    fmt.Println("Result and Error is:", res1, e) 
  
}
```

But it does not work:

```
Result and Error is: true <nil>
```

While it should return `false <nil>`.

How can I fix [this](https://play.golang.org/p/OzOFqYgYIEp)?

Comment: Just use `strings.IndexByte(s1, '.') != -1` or `strings.Index(s1, p1) != -1`

Comment: Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6770898/unknown-escape-sequence-error-in-go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` is a special character in a regular expression matching any single character. To match it literally, it needs to be escaped: `"\\."`.

The backslash is doubled because we need to escape its special meaning in a string literal.

Comment: Well actaully I tried to escape using `"\."` but it did not work. Why should we use `\\` twice?

Comment: One is for the regular expression, the other to get it literally into the string (because `\\` has a special meaning in string literals).